# MVC EF - EditorFor adds changes to model, CheckboxFor does not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm developing a webapplication in MVC and encountered a problem.
When using

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsChecked.Value)
```

and posting back to the controller. The objects does not get modified.

When i try using EditorFor the object gets modified but the checkbox is now a DropDownList. The solution for that issue is using CheckBoxFor so i am pretty stuck.

This is the part that handles it.

```
  @model List<Models.intake_Answers>

  @{var i =0;}

  //Viewbag is used to work with 2 models.
  @foreach (Models.intake item in ViewBag.Questions)
  {

  <tr>

            <td class="question">@Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(item.Question_localized.ToString())</td>

          //IMPORTANT PART

            <td class="answer">@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].IsChecked, new { @Value = true })</td>
            @{i++;}
   </tr>
  }
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: You are not showing where you are `POST`ing. Please display that. Also you code on your view could be a lot easier if you removed the dynamic `ViewBag` data.

Comment: ' [HttpPost]
        public  ActionResult Register(users u, adress a,List<intake_Answers>list) '

This is the controller where it's being send too.  


The ViewBag's are used to work with multiple Models. I don't see how i could do it otherwise

Answer (score 0):

If EditorFor is working then maybe all you need is to [create a custom EditorTemplate](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/extending-editor-templates-for-asp.net-mvc/) to display however you want if you don't like the default dropdown.  One of the EditorFor overrides will also let you pass in a template name if the name doesn't match the object type as the examples show.

[Here is another EditorTemplate example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot! i'll try this out.

Comment: I read the two articles and tried it out. It Works! Thanks
I added a View like this.
`@model bool?
@Html.CheckBox("", false) `